# Ajax insert data into DB even if php statement return false

Tags: php, ajax

**index.php**

```
<form action="../inc/q_camp.php" method="POST" class="modalForm">
        <h3>Campaign</h3><br>
        <label>Name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="campName" required><br>
        <label>Customer</label><br>
        <select name="client" required>
          <option value="1">Abc</option>
        </select><br>
        <label>Start in</label><br>
        <input type="date" name="campStart" id="cStrt" required><br>
        <label>End in</label><br>
        <input type="date" name="campStop" required><br>
        <input type="button" name="toStore" value="Next">
    </form>
```

**ajax.js**

```
/*This function submit ".modalForm"*/
function submitForm1(){
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../inc/q_camp.php",
        data: $(".modalForm").serialize()
    });
}

/*When the button with name "toStore" is pressed, call submitForm1*/
$("input[name=toStore]").click(function(){
    submitForm1();
});
```

**q_camp.php**

```
/*Submit the campaign*/
if(!empty($_POST['campName']) || !empty($_POST['client']) || 
    !empty($_POST['campStart']) || !empty($_POST['campStop']))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO campaigns(cmp_name, customer_id, cmp_start, cmp_stop) VALUES (:cName,:cId,:cStr,:cStp)";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam('cName', $_POST['campName']);
    $query->bindParam('cId', $_POST['client']);
    $query->bindParam('cStr', $_POST['campStart']);
    $query->bindParam('cStp', $_POST['campStop']);
    $query->execute();
}else print_r("Failed");
```

The ajax function insert in the database even if the php if statement is not satisfied... If I let the "campName" input empty, I get "Failed" but the row is inserted in the database like "cmp_id 1, cmp_name NOTHING, customer_id 1, cmp_start 00-00-0000, cmp_stop 00-00-0000".

In the database, all field are setted to NOT NULL.

I want to understand how AJAX can access the SQL Query even if the if statement from PHP isn't satisfied, how a row can be inserted even if the column is setted to null and what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: If all fields are required, use && condition instead of ||, browser may bypass required fields and submit empty data,
It's good practice to validate data both side, client side and server side.

Comment: You're using OR operator to validate. OR operator means If any condition satisfies then you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer @Smartpal ! It works with && instead of || but the if statement still return the else condition... I can't understand how the AJAX can insert the query even if the PHP if statement isn't satisfied..

Comment: @RobertBalaurea You are missing else brackets

Comment: Thanks @SaadSuri. The query worked now only if all fields are filled but still the if statement from php isn't satisfied...

Comment: @Smartpal I tried... Is the same result with else brackets.

Comment: try to add in click event `return false`

Comment: @RobertBalaurea submitForm1() is returning ajax request, may be this causes problem,
Or may cache, have you tried from other browsers?

Comment: and change `<select name="customer" required>` to `<select name="client" required>`

Comment: @Rainmx93 same result